# How split a string in c with comma

Tags: c, string, split

I created a function to split a string with comma.

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char splitted_line[8][50];

void split(char *line){
    
    printf("line 9\n");
    char *part = strtok(line, ",");
    printf("line 11\n");

    for(int i=1; i<8; i++){
        strcpy(splitted_line[i], part);
        printf("%s\n", splitted_line[i]);
        part = strtok(NULL, ",");
    }
}

int main(){
    char *line = "123,456,789";
    split(line);
    return 0;   
}
```

but the result after running is :

```
line 9
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

it seems the problem is in `char *part = strtok(line, ",");` but I don't know what's that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strtok()` will modify passed original string directly.

You must not modify string literals.

```
char *line = "123,456,789";
```

should be modifyable array

```
char line[] = "123,456,789";
```

Also don't forget to check if `part` is not `NULL` before doing `strcpy(splitted_line[i], part);`.

Comment: it works thanks! but how can I use function in this way `split("123,456,789");`. it has the same result `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Comment: Then copy passed string inside `split` and use it for `strtok`.